# Get value from service.yml

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I would like to create constants value for all my application.

In order to do that, the documentation seems to do something like that, in app/config/services.yml

```
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value
    CODE_OK: !php/const 200
    CODE_CREATED: !php/const 201
    CODE_MISSING_ARG : !php/const 400
    CODE_INVALID_ARG : !php/const 419
```

Now I would like to be able to use those values inside a Controller...but I can't find the good way.May be using the service.yml isn't the right way.

Comment: Instead - create a class with constants.

Comment: But why should I do that ? I don't know those constant belong to a class. I just want them to be available everywhere. I mean, I would set them in a class if I had the need to change them at some point in the application. But I don't.

Comment: Class constants are available __everywhere__. And you should do that because these constants will __hardly__ change in the future and they don't depend from the environment.

Comment: even with multiple bundles ? They won't be available only in the bundle where the class is ? I'm not that sure

Comment: This should definitely be in a class. Parameters as their name suggests are ... parameters.
Maybe you should take a look about how POO work

Comment: `use MyBundle\MyConstantsClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
$this->container->getParameter($varName);
```

You can inject the parameters as constructors argument or use autowiring in the method too.

If you're willing to use php constants as in your exemple, you probably should keep it that way with the parameters.

If not, I suggest you to create a class with constants.

```
abstract class Constants
{
   const VAR = 'content';
}
```

And use it that way elsewhere:

```
$var = Constants::VAR;
```

The class doesn't have to be abstract but since it won't be instanciated...

Note that using parameters directly from the controller is not really advised, as parameters should be used in services.

Comment: Great answer, deleted mine:) But I think that using container parameters inside controllers is bad practice overall. Although it is possible, one should note that Controller class is deprecated in actual Symfony revision, so non-ContainerAware AbstractController is suggested to be used, and this fact will make your life more difficult while porting to SF 4.2. My vote is for abstract class populated with constants - nice and eloquent solution.

Comment: So what you suggest is that they should only be used in a service ? You're probably right indeed. Especially as it goes to the "thin controller" principle. Actually, I'll update my answer.
About the AbstractController, it seems it still has access to the container :
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php

Comment: The AbstractController only has access to a small subset of services that it subscribes to.  There is a [parameter bag service](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-getting-container-parameters-as-a-service) that you can inject as needed.  But class constants are the way to go for this use case.